# OracleDataReader & datadridview list

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview

I try read data from oracle db and set data to datagridview component but I dont know where is the problem datagridview is empty, if I test reader throught while loop and get values I see all rows:

CODE:

```
Dbc dbc = new Dbc();
        dbc.connect();

        try
        {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + _tname;
            OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(sql, dbc.getConnection());

            OracleDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();


            tableListhist.ColumnCount = reader.FieldCount;



           for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; ++i)
            {
                tableListhist.Columns[i].HeaderText = reader.GetName(i).ToLower();
            }

            //tableListhist.DataMember = _tname;
            tableListhist.DataSource = reader;




            reader.Close();
            tableListhist.ReadOnly = true;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            dbc.close();
        }
```

But datagridview is empty :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you pass a DataTable or a DataSet as value for the DataSource property

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
tableListhist.DataSource = dt;
```